# Vim: VimRepress and Wordpress.com - how to insert code snippets?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I've started using Vim and [VimRepress plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3510) to blog. My blog is on  Wordpress.com - so I cannot install plugins etc. 
A lot of my posts have code snippets in them - and in Markdown syntax, I indent them 4 spaces so they get rendered as a pre/code tag. Is there anyway to mimic the behavior of the Wordpress.com [sourcecode] tag so I can get proper syntax highlighted code snippets in my blog posts?

http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've discovered that the WP.com `[sourcecode language="xxx"]` tags work with markdown/VimRepress with a caveat - Dont have any empty lines in the code. It may work properly with 4 spaces on the line - but haven't tried that yet.